# Purge a URL from the Fastly CDN via API call with curl or wget

Tags: bash, curl, wget, cdn, fastly

I use a bash script to deploy a static webpage which uses Fastly as a CDN. When `/example.html` gets deployed I would like to purge `/example.html` via their API within the bash script. I know that there is a good to go Ruby gem but I'd like to do it with `curl` or `wget` within the bash script.

How can I purge a given URL via the Fastly API with `curl` or `wget`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via

> curl -X PURGE http://www.example.com/image.jpg

as explained in their [docs](https://docs.fastly.com/api/purge).